# argument argparse with multiple value can't be detected as array

Tags: python, argparse

I have docker image with argparse below under main.py

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# mandatory parameter
parser.add_argument("--ds", help="ds", default=None)
parser.add_argument("--env", help="env", default=None)
parser.add_argument("--countries", help="country list", nargs='+', default=None)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

If I try run that using command line

```
python main.py \
--ds 2022-08-30
--env stg
--countries ID MY SG
```

it will return

```
Namespace(ds='2022-08-30', env='stg', countries=['ID', 'MY', 'SG'])
```

The result is expected because I want to have countries as array args.

But when I call the the file in KubernetesPodOperator as cmds parameter, it is detected as string

```
KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id=task_id,
    namespace="xxx",
    service_account_name="svc-acc",
    image=f"gcr.io/path/to/image",
    image_pull_policy="Always",
    cmds=['python',
          'main.py',
          '--ds=2022-08-30',
          '--env=stg',
          "--countries=ID MY SG"
         ],
    startup_timeout_seconds=300,
    dag=dag,
    **kwargs
)
```

result

```
Namespace(ds='2022-08-30', env='stg', countries=['ID MY SG'])
```

countries is detected as 1 string, then it become an array with 1 element instead of 3.
Is it possible to send the cmds as array to the input of command line? How to do that ya?
I have tried this also

```
cmds=['python',
          'main.py',
          '--ds=2022-08-30',
          '--env=stg',
          "--countries=['ID', 'MY', 'SG']"
         ],
```

and the result is

```
Namespace(ds='2022-08-30', env='stg', countries=["['ID', 'MY', 'SG']"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're passing it as one parameter. What you want to do is separate the spaces into different elements of the list:

```py
KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id=task_id,
    namespace="xxx",
    service_account_name="svc-acc",
    image=f"gcr.io/path/to/image",
    image_pull_policy="Always",
    cmds=['python',
          'main.py',
          '--ds=2022-08-30',
          '--env=stg',
          "--countries=ID",
          "MY",
          "SG"
         ],
    startup_timeout_seconds=300,
    dag=dag,
    **kwargs
)
```

Comment: Hi @pigrammer I tried that but got an error `error: unrecognized arguments: MY SG`

Answer (score 0):

If possible to change the argparse arguments, possible to use `action='append'` for argument `--countries`

```
parser.add_argument("--countries", help="country list", action='append', default=None)
```

and KPO can be called using multiple arguments

```
    cmds=['python',
          'main.py',
          '--ds=2022-08-30',
          '--env=stg',
          "--countries=ID",
          "--countries=MY",
          "--countries=SG"
         ],
```

it will return

```
Namespace(ds='2022-08-30', env='stg', countries=['ID', 'MY', 'SG'])
```

in the command line, call it using this command

```
python main.py \
--ds 2022-08-30 \
--env stg \
--countries ID --countries MY --countries SG
```